# SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module. Using express, no webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a npm module in the front end script. It is saying modules must be on top level to import but it is at the top level from what I can tell. Maybe my web server is messing with my code. I am unsure.

The code is ugly right now because I am trying to get everything situated.

I have already tried

```html
<script type='module' src='./js/scripts.js'></script>
```

scripts.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';


function getQueryStringValue (key) {  
    return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURIComponent(key).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));  
}  
const query = getQueryStringValue('code');

class chime {
    constructor(code) {
        this.code = code;
    };
    async logIn() {
        const response = await axios.post('url', {
            'client_id': '',
            'client_secret': '',
            'grant_type': '',
            'redirect_uri': 'https://localhost:3000',
            'code': this.code
        });

        console.log(response);
    }
    test() {
        console.log(this.code);
    }
}

if (query) {
    const client = new chime(query);

    client.logIn();

};
```

```js
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var https = require('https')
var app = express()
const path = require('path');

const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '../public');
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static(publicPath));



app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, '/index.html'));
});


https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/ssl/server.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname+ '/ssl/server.cert'))
}, app)
    .listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000! Go to https://localhost:3000/')
    });
```

I am wanting to be able to import npm modules.

Answer (score 4):

> `import axios from 'axios';`

Bare module imports won't work in the browser. You need to use relative paths to a file that can be served by your web server (and not simply the NPM package name/a module exported by a package in `node_modules` and not a served directory), or a toolchain that can use a provided project root to generate the relative paths/pull in code from `node_modules` into a bundle.

> It is saying modules must be on top level to import but it is at the top level from what I can tell

You didn't provide your entire setup, but using the implied hierarchy, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".` in Chrome, which is consistent with the above issue.

Comment: never faced this problem in previous projects, not even when deploying to a web server. Tried import axios from '../../node_modules/axios/index'; still got the same error.

Comment: I took a quick look at axios (which I've never used), and it doesn't export ES modules. It natively uses CommonJS, and uses Webpack to generate an AMD-compatible distribution. You'd need to generate your own ES module distribution, or use existing AMD imports. You're also not serving your `node_modules` directory as far as I can tell, and your import needs to resolve to a filename your server can serve - the missing extension would likely be an issue. It seems there might be some other issue that can't be reproduced without your project being available.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way is to use the cdn:

```
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

put it in your html file above your JavaScript tag

---

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

    <script type='module' src="../app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spent 2 hours and finally find a solution, the first thing you need to do is

```
npm i parcel-bundler -D
```

then package.json add the following two-line of codes

```
"scripts": {
"dev": "parcel index.html",
"build": "parcel build index.html"
}
```

finally

```
npm run dev.
```

and if you still have trouble, please [open this link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-axios-vanilla-js) it just saves me so many hours.