# importing npm package to public folder in Express.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, import

I have a simple Express.js application. Problem is that I can't import any npm package (axios in this case) in client javascript code which is in `/public` folder.
This package is installed using `npm install axios`. Folder structure of my application is following:

```
node_modules
public
  |-- main.js // here i want to use axios
  |-- style.css
views
  |-- index.ejs
package-lock.json
package.json
server.js
```

server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index');
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}...`));
```

package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1", // not working
    "ejs": "^3.1.6", // working
    "express": "^4.17.1" // working
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7" // working
  }
```

main.js file is linked in index.ejs with following script:

```
<script type="module" defer src="main.js"></script>
```

And main.js file:

```
import axios from "axios"; // not working, can't import
//import axios from "../node_modules/axios/dist/axios"; // i also tried this, but not working too

console.log('hey!'); // working, so file is successfully loaded in browser

axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => console.log(res.data)) // error
```

In the browser console is an error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "axios". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`
If I use import `"../node_modules/axios/dist/axios"` error change on: `GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/axios/dist/axios net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`. So what's the problem with this? How can I solve this? This is quite similar like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55886312/syntaxerror-import-declarations-may-only-appear-at-top-level-of-a-module-using). But I don't want to use any module bundler or axios added via url for this.

Comment: if you want to use 'import' keyword you will need to add 'type':'module' to your package.json but the simple solution is maybe to use 'require' instead of 'import'  :  `const axios = require('axios').default;`  (cf github readme)